# Android singlechoiceitem dialog

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a dialog like so.

```
AlertDialog.Builder mySortAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,
    AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);
mySortAlertDialog.setTitle("Sort by?");
String[] r = {
    "Firstname", "Lastname"
};
mySortAlertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(r, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }
});
```

This create two choices and now I need a button to confirm the users choice. So I do that like so:

```
 mySortAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {@
         Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
```

Now the problem is. I have two listeners, one to check which option is selected and the other to confirm the choice and do logic using the values from the first listener.

My question is, how do I make these two listeners interact so that the user selects either firstname or lastname and then presses OK and then logic is performed based on the choice.

Thanks.

EDIT: this is what my dialog looks like...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code, this should work perfectly. (Use `AlertDialog`.**getListView**`#getCheckedItemPosition`)

```
AlertDialog.Builder mySortAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
mySortAlertDialog.setTitle("Sort by?");
String[] r = {"Firstname", "Lastname"};
mySortAlertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(r, 0, null);

mySortAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Selected: " + ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 });
 mySortAlertDialog.create().show();
```

Comment: theres a red line under mContext in the onClick method saying it cannot be resolved to a variable. What is it supposed to be?

Comment: sorry use `this` instead

Comment: "this" didn't work either because it was refering to the DialogInterface, I just used "getApplicationContext()" and it worked perfectly, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Just one small question, You say mySortAlertDialog.create().show() and all this time, i've been saying mySortAlertDialog.show() without the create(). Does this matter?

Comment: Oh in the `Toast.makeText`, this should be any context, and anyway I suppose you do not want to keep the toast. As for your question, No it does not matter. Check the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#show()

Answer (score 1):

Replace this code.

```
mySortAlertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(r, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
});
```

with

```
mySortAlertDialog.setItems(r, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
});
```

Then try to put positive button in dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You can use as below:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder mySortAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            mySortAlertDialog.setTitle("Sort by?");
            String[] r = { "Firstname", "Lastname" };
            String selectedText = "";
            mySortAlertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(r, -1,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            selectedText = r[which];
                        }
                    });

            mySortAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Use selectedText here

                }
            });
```